# what is the efficient way to minimize page slowdown with around 5500 link

Tags: javascript, html

i have a php page with an Jw audio player, and have around 5500 links, on each link's onclick event a javascript function is attached. php is producing the exact relative path  and name of files and is then passed to javascript.

```
<a class="items" href="#" 
onclick="play1('<?php echo $fname."'".","."'".$f; ?>');return false">
<?php echo($fname);?>
</a>
```

initially i wrapped it inside `<li>`, had a image inside this, and the above `<a>`. My page(Obviously) is slow, the player takes time to load the files, i have removed the `<li>` tags now, its plain simple 5500 `<a>` tags now, page is much more responsive now.
I want to what is that thing that causes the page to became slower, is it simply so many links inside `<li>` or the javascript function attached to it.

What would be the most efficient way to handle this situation, what could be the lightest tag that i can use, so that i can minimize the overhead as much as possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need 5500 links all at once on the page? Why not implement some sort of search or filter or paging feature?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen thats the thing, i need those many links on the page

Comment: @Lowkase no pagination, i cannot use it,otherwise that was the first thing in my mind. at least on one page i have to show all the files, then on rest i can categorize them.

Comment: Can you explain why you need 5500 links then? Is it for SEO?

Comment: Are you using a loop to build the filename for each link?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen no no it is like a music library, and also, i am not stressing on ONLY links, i can put them as text, page becames much better with texts, but then how would i know which text was click, i need to have some tag, so that i can attach event to it.

Comment: So you're offering a _human_ user a list of 5500 things to click on? That just doesn't make sense. You should take a step back a reevaluate how you want your UX to be.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen lol, but i need this.

Answer (score 2):

I think the main issue is having that many links on a page to begin with, and then whatever overhead you have on top of that - javascript, headers from server to browser, etc. The only way to make something like that quick is to generate the page simply with `<a>` and `<br/>`s.

Saying that, the JavaScript would have added to the overhead a bit to, slowing it down, the rendering of the `<li>` elements, the player loading, sending the music (I assume it's video or music) to the user, loading it's content into the browser, etc. Usually, these things - minus the player loading and streaming the content - can be done fast, but when you account for that many elements, it definitely will add up. The only way that page will get decent response times is purely using `<a>` and `<br />`, and having a separate page handle the actual media playing. I would suggest pagination though as mentioned in the comments, or something similar if you can get away with it.

Comment: you are right, i just removed that jw audio player, and its libs, and added a simple html5 audio player, the page is smoooth..:)

Answer (score 1):

Is your page still slow whith only `<a>` ? What was the structure of the page with `<li>` ?

You might get some performance improvement by using a single javascript handler on an element that is the parent of the `<a>`s, and let the event bubble to know which link was clicked. (See http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate ..)

Comment: with `li` it was heavy because of small image in it and other css maybe, but with pure `a` and html5 player, it is very smooth. also thanks for the link, i will implement it.